# In UrbanCode Deploy, how do I cause an application process to fail if not all component versions were specified?

Tags: ucd

Currently, when I run an application process that installs various components, if I don't specify a version for any of them, the deploy component process doesn't run, and it says "No Version Selected".  However, the step doesn't fail, and the process continues.  Is there a way to configure the process to fail if not all components have a version?  Or is there a way for me to interrogate the manifest for the process in a step at the top to figure it out myself and fail accordingly?  I currently can find no way to do either of these things.  The version of UCD I am using is 6.1.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If your component process is configured as "Process Type* Operational (With Version)" then if you don't select the version the job will fail.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, the component process needs to be a Deployment type because it should be interacting with inventory and compliance.  However, I hadn't noticed that about Operational (with version) type processes before.  I supposed I could look at using Operational with version and managing the inventory changes manually.  Something to think about.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisRatcliffe Did you try using Utility Steps->"Add Inventory Status" as part of your component process, that will take care of adding the version to inventory.